# session in php changes logged in users data on opening on multiple tabs

Tags: php

plz suggest me...

my project has 3 department.
paginetion , ctp ,machine
when user is logged in it goes to their respective department page after login.
but when i open two login on different tabs on browser. the webpage change user login automatically.

for ex-- if i login on pagination dept. on one tab and  also logged in with ctp dept on another tab in browser then , it loads the data of pagination department in to the ctp department and also change the user of ctp to pagination users.

below is my login code

```
<?php 
  $usermaster = new usermaster;
  if(isset($_POST['login']))
  {   
$city = make_safe($_POST['city']);
        $username = make_safe($_POST['username']);
        $password = make_safe($_POST['password']);          
        $result = $usermaster->select($usermaster->table,'',"username='$username' AND password='$password' AND city='$city'",'');

    if(count($result))
        {        
           $_SESSION ['Auth']['id'] = $result['id'];        
           $_SESSION['Auth'] = $result[0];        
           unset($_SESSION['Auth']['password']);                  
           $_SESSION['city'] = $_REQUEST['city'];                  
          if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'Pagination')
          {
             header ("Location: main.php");
              exit;
          }
          else
          if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'CTP')
          {
             header ("Location: ctp_final.php");
              exit;
          }
          else
          if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'Machine')
          {
             header ("Location: machine_final.php");
              exit;
          } 
          else
          if($_SESSION['Auth']['department'] == 'LocalAdmin')
          {
             header ("Location: city_report.php");
              exit;
          }     
           }
          else
          { 
            $_SESSION['message1'] = "Wrong user Name or password";
             header ("Location: index.php");    
              exit;

          }          

  }
 ?>
```

this code is check session on every department page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['Auth']['id']) || (trim($_SESSION['Auth']['id']) == '')) {
         header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You might wanna check the session on login page and if the user is already logged in then redirect to appropriate page.

Comment: when i logged in with user1 it redirect to pagination dept. after that whein i loggen in with user2 it redirects to ctp dept. but after page refresh user1 load the data of user2 automatically.